# Rcpp numeric vector output returns only one value

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

So I'm having a little trouble returning values from the function I created using RCPP. It only returns the first value of the NumericVector. The issue is when I call the function within itself and pass the NumericVector back to the out variable. Any input as to what I am doing incorrectly would be much appreciated.

```
NumericVector advantage(double tRos, double tTat, double cRos, double cTat){
double tRosAd = 0;
double tTatAd = 0;
double ja = 0;
double rosAtt = 0;
double tatAtt = 0;
double ttlAd = 0;
NumericVector out(1);

if ((tRos >= 0 || cRos >=0) && cRos >= tRos && cTat <= tTat){
    //case 1.1//
    tRosAd = (cRos - tRos) * cTat * -1;
    tTatAd = (tTat - cTat) * tRos;
    out[0] = tRosAd;
    out[1] = tTatAd;
}
else if((tRos >= 0 && cRos >= 0) && cRos <= tRos && cTat >= tTat){
    //case 1.2//
    out = advantage(cRos, cTat, tRos, tTat);
    out[0] = out[0] * -1;
    out[1] = out[1] * -1;
}
else if(tRos >= 0 && cRos <= 0 && tTat >= cTat){
    //case 2.1//
    tRosAd = (tRos - cRos) * cTat;
    tTatAd = (tTat - cTat) * tRos;
    out[0] = tRosAd;
    out[1] = tTatAd;
}
else if(tRos <= 0 && cRos >= 0 && tTat <= cTat){
    //case 2.2//
    out = advantage(cRos, cTat, tRos, tTat);
    out[0] = out[0] * -1;
    out[1] = out[1] * -1;
}
else if(tRos <= 0 && cRos <= 0 && tTat >= cTat & tRos >= cRos){
    //case 3.1//
    tRosAd = (tRos - cRos) * cTat;
    tTatAd = (tTat - cTat) * tRos;
    out[0] = tRosAd;
    out[1] = tTatAd;
}
else if(tRos <= 0 && cRos <= 0 && tTat <= cTat && tRos <= cRos){
    //case 3.2//
    out = advantage(cRos, cTat, tRos, tTat);
    out[0] = out[0] * -1;
    out[1] = out[1] * -1;
}
else if(tRos >= 0 && cRos >=  0 && tTat >= cTat && tRos >= cRos){
    //case 4.1//
    //calculate two attribution advantages//
    tRosAd = (tRos - cRos) * cTat;
    tTatAd = (tTat - cTat) * cRos;
    //calculate total & joint advantage//
    ttlAd = (tTat * tRos) - (cTat * cRos);
    ja = ttlAd - (tRosAd + tTatAd);
    rosAtt = tRosAd / (tRosAd / tTatAd);
    tatAtt = tTatAd / (tRosAd / tTatAd);
    //add joint advantage//
    tRosAd = ja * rosAtt + tRosAd;
    tTatAd = ja * tatAtt + tTatAd;
    out[0] = tRosAd;
    out[1] = tTatAd;
}
else if(tRos >= 0 && cRos >= 0 && tTat <= cTat && tRos <= cRos){
    //case 4.2//
    out = advantage(cRos, cTat, tRos, tTat);
    out[0] = out[0] * -1;
    out[1] = out[1] * -1;
}
else if(tRos <= 0 && cRos <= 0 && tTat <= cTat && tRos >= cRos){
    //case 5.1//
    tRosAd = (tRos - cRos) * tTat;
    tTatAd = (cTat - tTat) * tRos * -1;
    //calculate total and joint advantage//
    ttlAd = (tTat * tRos) - (cTat * cRos);
    ja = ttlAd - (tRosAd + tTatAd);
    rosAtt = tRosAd / (tRosAd + tTatAd);
    tatAtt = tTatAd / (tRosAd + tTatAd);
    tRosAd = ja * rosAtt + tRosAd;
    tTatAd = ja * tatAtt + tTatAd;
    out[0] = tRosAd;
    out[1] = tTatAd;
}
else if(tRos <= 0 && cRos <= 0 && tTat >= cTat && tRos <= cRos){
    //case 5.2//
    out = advantage(cRos, cTat, tRos, tTat);
    out[0] = out[0] * -1;
    out[1] = out[1] * -1;
}
return out;
}
```

Comment: `NumericVector out(1)` creates a vector of length 1...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Hadley's comment noted `NumericVector out(1)` creates a new instance of length one.

You got lucky that the code did not blow up when you accessed two elements repeated via `out[0]` and `out[1]`.

If you know the length `n` of your vector, use it:  `NumericVector out(n)`.  Else resize later though that may lose your content.

If you do not know length of your vector, grow an `std::vector` dynamically and convert when returning to R.  There are numerous examples for either approach.